# Why \& becomes 'and'?

Tags: symbols

When I type in '&' for sure I got error, then I tried '\&', the output is the text word 'and'.

Can someone tell me how does this happen? I tried $\&$ and {\&}, and they did not work. Do I need some usepackage to support in displaying '&'???

Input is: [image]

Output is: [image]

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Under normal circumstances an `&` is a special character (used for alignments), so you need to escape it: `\&`. But also under normal conditions, an `\&` produces "&", and not "and", so you probably have some setting overriding this default. Please make a small compilable document that demonstrates the issue (a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)).

Answer (score 10):

Any tex command can be redefined at any time (which is why a complete document test is almost always required)

earlier in your document you will have some definition equivalent to

```
\renewcommand\&{ and }
```

If you don't want to remove this definition, you can use `\string&` to get a `&`